# SIGSEGV when parsing string with JsonCpp

Tags: c++, jsoncpp

I have a task serialized as JSON:

```
{
  text: "Some task",
  status: 1
}
```

I'm using this function inside a `Serialize` namespace:

```
Task parseTask(std::string task) {
    Json::Value root;
    Json::Reader reader;

    if(reader.parse(task, root, false)) {
        std::string text = root["text"].asString();
        int status = root["status"].asInt();

        Task result(text);
        if(status == 1) result.setCompleted();
        return result;
    }
}
```

I'm calling the function as follow:

```
Task t = Serialize::parseTask("{ text: \"Some Task\", status: 1 }");
```

And compiling with `-ljsoncpp` option. However I get:

```
terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

I've been sweeping trough JsonCpp documentation but can't seem to find whats wrong with my code.

Comment: This sort of error is usually very simple to trace back using a debugger.

Comment: Would you consider the json parser in Qt? That is the faster out there. It even beats the well-known C json parser! I can give you benchmarks if you wish.

Comment: GDB throws only Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0xb7e0e6f2 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6. Not very informative

Comment: There is no return when parse fails.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at your code, but your JSON is not valid.  Key names must be surrounded with quotation marks.  Try:

```
Task t = Serialize::parseTask("{ \"text\": \"Some Task\", \"status\": 1 }");
```

Comment: Using this valid JSON will avoid to execute the wrong code (no return) when a parse occurs, but the code is still wrong.